# Creating data frame out of sequence using toDF method in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I use Spark 2.4.4 and try to get a data frame given below.

```
val spark =  SparkSession
            .builder
            .master("local[*]")
            .appName("App")
            .getOrCreate 

import spark.sqlContext.implicits._  
import spark.implicits._

val justNow = spark.sparkContext.parallelize( 
        Seq(Row("1", "One")
           ,Row("2", "Tow")
        )
).toDF
```

I have the above piece of code defined inside main method. But I am getting an error that toDF is not function defined in RDD. I referred other posts on stackoverflow to include the explicits to get rid of the errors. I am still getting it.

```
error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value toDF'?
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
```

Can someone please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `createDataFrame` method instead. toDF is not suitable for RDD of Rows.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("col1",StringType), StructField("col2",StringType)))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(Seq(Row("1", "One"),Row("2", "Tow"))), schema)

df.show
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|   1| One|
|   2| Tow|
+----+----+
```

Comment: Yes mck. This one works well. jJst trying to understand why the toDF is not working as mentioned in the spark textbook and other writeups. Thanks!

Comment: I might be wrong, but toDF works for RDD of Array/Seq etc, but not for RDD[Row].

Comment: @user3103957, hi you cannot create df out of collection of Row objects implicitly without specifying schema. And yes it works with other collection of objects but not with Row.